# How i can filter this map to generating sql update more elegant and clean?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

**I have this map:**

```
Map<String, String> strMap = new HashMap<>();
```

**and i put this itens him:**

```
strMap.put("A1565ZMM", "35;9109890019;35;127;A1565ZMM;01280651687;12458754;3;15439443");
strMap.put("A1558IE8", "35;9109890019;35;127;A1558IE8;01280651687;11034003;3;15439443");
strMap.put("A1565ZN2", "35;9109890019;38;127;A1565ZN2;01280651687;12458761;3;15439520");
strMap.put("A1558IID", "35;9109890019;38;127;A1558IID;01280651687;11034143;3;15439520");
strMap.put("A1567OR5", "35;9109890019;39;127;A1567OR5;01280651687;12534143;3;15532787");
strMap.put("A1558IQ2", "35;9109890019;39;127;A1558IQ2;01280651687;11034367;3;15532787");
strMap.put("A155YM40", "35;9109890019;40;127;A155YM40;01280651687;12201754;3;14210415");
strMap.put("A1558IOA", "35;9109890019;40;127;A1558IOA;01280651687;11034318;3;14210415");
strMap.put("A1565ZNE", "35;9109890027;3 ;127;A1565ZNE;01001671600;12458774;3;15436154");
strMap.put("A1558J1J", "35;9109890027;3 ;127;A1558J1J;01001671600;11034759;3;15436154");
```

**this is code i want write this better, but i cant see how**
**how i can write code more elegant?**

```
List<String> tuple = mapaResgatesSQL.values().stream().map(u -> 
                    new StringBuilder("UPDATE <TABLE> SET STATUS = 12 WHERE ID = ")
                        .append(u.split(";")[3])
                        .append(" AND IDAAA = ")
                        .append(u.split(";")[6])
                        .append(" AND IDBBB = '")
                        .append(u.split(";")[5])
                        .append("' AND CODCCC = ")
                        .append(u.split(";")[4])
                        .append(" AND IDDDD = ")
                        .append(u.split(";")[1])
                        .append(" AND NUMEEE = ")
                        .append(u.split(";")[2])
                        .append(";")
                        .toString()
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());

tuple.add("COMMIT;");
```

Comment: The readability question aside, one thing you need to change here is your repeated calls to `u.split(";")`

Comment: You should use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: What are you going to do with the `tuple` list? Are you going to add batches to a prepared statement?

Comment: Tks for answers. @ernest_k i really want create a batch update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get one step cleaner using a format:

```
public static final String QUERY = "UPDATE <TABLE> SET STATUS = 12 WHERE ID = %s AND IDAAA = %s AND IDBBB = '%s' AND CODCCC = %s AND IDDDD = %s AND NUMEEE = %s";
```

and further `split`ting once as:

```
List<String> tuple = mapaResgatesSQL.values().stream()
        .map(s -> s.split(";"))
        .map(splits -> String.format(QUERY, splits[3], splits[6], splits[5], splits[4], splits[1], splits[2]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create update SQL statement with placeholders in it

```
String updateSql = "UPDATE <TABLE> SET STATUS = 12 WHERE ID = %s AND IDAAA = % AND IDBBB = %s AND CODCCC = %s AND IDDDD = %s AND NUMEEE = %s;";
```

ANd then use [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to replace with values, like below example

```
List<String> list = mapaResgatesSQL.values()
                                   .stream().map(str -> str.split(";"))
                                   .map(arr -> String.format(updateSql, arr[3], arr[6],arr[5],arr[4],arr[1],arr[2]))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```